# How to change spacing between letters and Lines on UICell using swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

[image]

i am using  custom table view cells and dynamically size them to fit their contents(using constraints on UICell) , but i can't able to control  the Spacing  between the letter  and Lines ,i am using this code

```
   let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 40

        var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str!)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
```

Comment: for letter spacing somthing like kerning will help you

Answer (score 0):

For spacing between letters in objective c:

```
NSAttributedString * attributedString =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:text
     attributes: @{ NSKernAttributeName : @(1.20f) }];

    label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

1.20f is the space you want between your letters. label is a `UILabel`.

in swift:

```
http://rajiev.com/ios-font-kerning-with-swift-and-nsattributedstring/
```